# retrieving latest records From Table (Table having 3 dates column)

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a doubt.
If a table is having 3 dates columns then how to retrieve latest records from the table by comparing the three dates.
Is it possible to retrieve the records in sql.
i need latest 10 records which is having the latest date among the 3 columns

Comment: What are the three different datas ? And by which date you want to sort the records.

Comment: created date, last updated date and submitted date. are the columns

Comment: Now the question is you want to sort by which data/s ?

Comment: i need latest 10 records which is having the latest date among the 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try case..when..then like below:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Date1 >= Date2 AND Date1 >= Date3 THEN Date1
    WHEN Date2 >= Date1 AND Date2 >= Date3 THEN Date2
    WHEN Date3 >= Date1 AND Date3 >= Date2 THEN Date3
    ELSE                                        Date1
END AS RecentDate
FROM mytable
```

Comment: wow , its working but i need record not the date, and that records should be in ascending order.

Comment: You'd get the same result with `select GREATEST(Date1,Date2,Date3) as RecentDate from mytable`.

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select  * from  emp where emp.USER_ID='100'
Order by 
CASE
    WHEN CREATED_DATE >= LAST_UPDATED_ON AND CREATED_DATE >= SUBMITTED_DATE THEN CREATED_DATE 
    WHEN LAST_UPDATED_ON >= CREATED_DATE AND LAST_UPDATED_ON >= SUBMITTED_DATE THEN LAST_UPDATED_ON
    WHEN SUBMITTED_DATE >= CREATED_DATE AND SUBMITTED_DATE >= LAST_UPDATED_ON THEN SUBMITTED_DATE
    ELSE                                        CREATED_DATE 
END desc ) where rownum<=10;

this is the answer... thanks for help...